# Google Analytics tracking pdf downloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I have a problem with `Google Analytics`.

I want to track clicks on an `<a>` tag which links to a PDF file, for which I'm using a function which will be called when user clicks on download link.

Here is my code:

```
$('.dl-tracking').on('click', function (){
    ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'click', 'link');
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: try this `ga('send', 'event', 'what is doing', 'button-name');` with 4 parameters

Comment: Are u sure you attach auto generate script and that code 
`ga('create', 'xx-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');` in MasterPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code:

**1st Method:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dl-tracking').on('click', function (){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download']);
    });
  });

</script>
```

**2nd Method:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dl-tracking').on('click', function (){
        ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'click');
    });
  });

</script>
```

**NOTE**

Replace "UA-XXXXX-X" or "UA-XXXX-Y" with your own GA Tracking Code.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using universal.js...
I can see my events in the real time tracking.
But they doesn't appear in the content/events section:(
Whats going wrong here?

Comment: I updated the code to match the Universal Analytics code you're using.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work:(
I see the result in the real time tracking but not in content/event :(

Comment: I used the google analitycs debugger and this method is triggered.
There is an Event with my label and the category.
So why doesn't it appear in my google analytics account?

Comment: As far as I know, when you create a Google Analytics account you can't see the results for the first 24 hours, because otherwise some calculations will fail (division etc.). I don't know if it's the same for Event Tracking.

Comment: Now it's working.
It was my mistake. 
I only showed the results of yesterday and not today.... :D
So the code was allright!
Thank you!! :)